# Mrs. Johnson tell me that it (will take/ takes / must take / has taken) two more months to complete the project

Tags: tense, past-tense, modal-verbs, present-tense, future-constructions

[image]

This is a question from the entrance exam of a certain university in Tokyo.  You are supposed to choose the most appropriate phrase out of the four, but it confuses me.

- Mrs. Johnson tells me that it **(will take/ takes/ must take/ has
  taken)** two more months to complete the project.

I guess the correct answer will be 1, will take.  However, I don't understand why the others are incorrect.  Would you please kindly tell me what is wrong with the other three?

Comment: Same old same old... Garbage test, probably devised by a non-native Anglophone. Given the appropriate context, ***all*** of those "wrong" answers could be exactly what's needed. Almost certainly the contexts where ***will take*** would be the best (or *only*) possible choice will be more common than contexts where, say, ***has taken*** would make more sense. But it's a poor quality test - concerned with ***likely scenarios*** rather than ***syntactic validity***, so don't waste too much time on it.

Comment: "Two _more_ months" is most likely to mean "another two months added to the time it has taken until now", so the future "will take" is the most likely interpretation.

Comment: I assume 1 (will take) could be the best choice, but I don't understand why the others are marked wrong.  Does "must take" sound odd here?

Comment: All of them are *possible*, but only *will take* sounds natural.  "Must take" just doesn't make very much sense.  What would it even mean here?  "It is required that the project take two more months to complete"?

Comment: @stangdon: *only **will take** sounds natural*. That's only true in the most common context. It's perfectly possible that addressee has just said to Mrs Johnson *"Did you finish that project on time? The one management wanted to be over and done with by Christmas?"* But actually Mrs Johnson only finished the project a couple of weeks ago (it's now March). In *that* scenario, only ***has taken*** makes sense. Similar scenarios could be constructed to make any of the available choices the only one that made sense.

Comment: @stangdon You can use "must" when you are very sure of something, can't you?  As in "That man must be the burglar!"  Isn't it possible to say "it must take two more months to complete the project" when you are very sure that it will take two more months to complete the project?

Comment: @kuwabara Yes, you can use *must* like that, but if you try to use it that way, like "It must take two months to ____" it sounds like you're referring to a general fact or general situation.  For example, "They start from scratch every time?  It must take them six weeks to complete each project!"  But if I wanted to say "it must be the case that this particular project will require two months", it isn't a natural phrasing; I would say something like "This project will require at least two more months."

Comment: Does that mean you don't use "must" for future events no matter how positive you are?

Comment: We can say _It must be finished by Christmas_ (the last possible date for completion), but  it sounds odd to say _It must take two more months_ (as though the work has to be planned to last exactly two months). As @stangdon says, we would express it differently: _It will take at least two more months - We shall need another two months - It won't be finished for at least two months_.

Comment: D'accord.  So, when you use "must" for a future event, it is interpreted as a reference to an obligation, not to your confidence of the possibility of the event.  Am I right?

Comment: @kuwabara That sounds correct to me!

Answer (score 1):

These "choose the tense" questions are usually rubbish.  That is because "tense" is not a element of grammar that must agree internally, but an element that adds meaning.

Here the sentence says "two *more* months".  This is to indicate that the project isn't finished yet and so the finishing is in the future.  Hense "will take".

The simple present would be odd, as it means it always takes two more months.  That might be possible in an ironic sort of way - "These tasks are never complete, if you ask anyone they always say "two more months".  But this kind of irony is beyond such tests.

Similarly "must take" and "has taken" could be used given the right context, but would seem unlikely.  There would need to be more context to justify the use of "more" (two more than what??)

So it is clear that 1. is the right answer.  Not because it is the only possible answer, but because the others fit less well.

Comment: I wonder why must take sounds off here.  "Must" is often used when you very sure of something, isn't it?  Is it strange to say "it must take two more months to complete the project" when you are very sure that it will take two more months to complete the project?